# Appending new fields from another JOIN statements in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, field

So, I have 3 tables :

```
guest : 
id_guest | name
1        | John
2        | Nick
3        | James
4        | Paul
5        | Chris
6        | Karen
7        | Peter

room :  
id_room  | status
1        | Clean
2        | Dirty
3        | Dirty
4        | Clean
5        | Clean
6        | Clean

reservation : 
id_guest | id_room  | date
1        | 1        | 2015-04-15
1        | 1        | 2015-04-16
1        | 1        | 2015-04-17
2        | 3        | 2015-04-15
3        | 4        | 2015-04-15
3        | 4        | 2015-04-16
4        | 2        | 2015-04-16
5        | 2        | 2015-04-17
6        | 2        | 2015-04-18
```

And this is what the expected output should be :

```
id_room  | status   | d04-15    | d04-16    | d04-17    | d04-18
1        | Clean    | John      | John      | John      |
2        | Dirty    |           | Paul      | Chris     | Karen
3        | Dirty    | Nick      |           |           |
4        | Clean    | James     | James     |           |
5        | Clean    |           |           |           |
6        | Clean    |           |           |           |
```

I have been able to show it until the third field (d04-15) though with the date as values, using :

```
SELECT room.id_room,
       room.status,
       reservation.date AS d04-15
FROM room
LEFT JOIN reservation
ON room.id_room = reservation.id_room AND reservation.date = '2015-04-15'
GROUP BY room.id_room
```

But I'm not sure as to how to display the name there and 
appending new fields (d04-16, d04-17, and d04-18) from another JOIN statement.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns returned in a query can't be altered at run time; they have to be statically declared in the SQL SELECT statement.

Here's an example of a statement that can achieve the specified result:

```
SELECT m.id_room
     , m.status
     , MAX(IF(r.date='2015-04-15',g.name,NULL)) AS `d04-15`
     , MAX(IF(r.date='2015-04-16',g.name,NULL)) AS `d04-16`
     , MAX(IF(r.date='2015-04-17',g.name,NULL)) AS `d04-17`
     , MAX(IF(r.date='2015-04-18',g.name,NULL)) AS `d04-18`
  FROM room m
  LEFT
  JOIN reservation r
    ON r.id_room = m.id_room
   AND r.date IN ('2015-04-15','2015-04-16','2015-04-17','2015-04-18')
  LEFT
  JOIN guest g
    ON g.id_guest = r.id_guest
 GROUP BY m.id_room
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've tested it and it looks like what I've been looking for. Just a small typo though, I think r.reservation.date should be r.date, and there's a missing apostrophe right after 2015-04-16.

Comment: @jhnwck: good catch, i've corrected. This query assumes that the reservation tuple `(id_guest,id_room,date)` is unique. If that tuple is not, the GROUP BY will collapse the rows, and the "maximum" guest name will be returned. the other guest names will be discarded.